# Custom ListView with database

Tags: android, database, android-listview

**Here's my android code :**

```
public class Fragment1 extends SherlockFragment {
    ListView lista;
    ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
    private List<Listaadaptera> thelista = new ArrayList<Listaadaptera>();
    View rootView;
    ListView list;
    TextView title, price;

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        MenuInflater blowup = this.getSherlockActivity()
                .getSupportMenuInflater();
        blowup.inflate(R.menu.menuxml, menu);
        return;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pricelist, container, false);
        ActionBar ab = this.getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar();
        ab.setTitle("");
        title = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        price = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.details);

        list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
        SpinnerAdapter mSpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this.getSherlockActivity(), R.array.phones_array,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        ab.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
        ab.setListNavigationCallbacks(mSpinnerAdapter, null);
        StrictMode.enableDefaults();
        getData();
        return rootView;
}
getdata();
*//Connecting to the database...

        try {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                thelista.add(new Listaadaptera(json.getString("PhoneName"),
                        json.getString("PhonePrice"), R.drawable.lebanon,
                        R.drawable.rating));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("lag_tag", "ERROR PARSING DATA" + e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getSherlockActivity(),
                    "Couldn't Connect To The Internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }

    }

}
```

pricelist xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
        android:padding="3dip" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/list_image"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:text="Smartphone Name"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/details"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:text="Smartphone Price"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="10dip" />


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/rating" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My goal in this code, is to get all the details registered in the database and detail them into this costume layout.
In the table i have the 2 fields, PhoneName and PhonePrice
How to make my application able to get all the details found in these fields and detail them in listview? 
Your help will be appreciated a lot! Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

Try using this codes

```
         Cursor select = db.rawQuery("Select *from DBName", null);
         select.moveToFirst();
         int count = c.getCount();   
         String[] pname= new String[count];
         String[] pprice= new String[count];
         c.moveToFirst();
         for(int i = 0;i < count;i++){
                pname[i] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("PhoneName"));
                pprice[i] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("PhonePrice"));
                c.moveToNext();
            }
         ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.menulist);
         list.setAdapter(new listadapter(this,pname,pprice));
```

"listadapter" should have 2 values for your PhoneName and Phone Address. And use holder so your list view will not encounter a problem like repeating value.

this codes work's for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use an ArrayAdapter to map the values you get from the database to the row xml you will use to display the data in the ListView

Comment: I had my application working in the past with the standard listview, but i couldn't get my application working on a costume listview...

Comment: That was my old code : 
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

   String name = json.getString("PhoneName");
    items.add(name);
    ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
    thelista.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter);

Comment: I mean, the class were you are extending ListView

Comment: Also, may I know why are you extending ListView?

Comment: i posted it into the question. Any suggestion?

Comment: I do not understand. What do you want to achieve by extending ListView? Where is your class that extends ListView?